# Want to know how to get each element occurring in how many items? Like 1 is occurring twice in two arrays items and items3 in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have **scraped** the data from a website and 100s of arrays gives various options that the arrays can choose and I want to know how many times that option was chosen by all those arrays.

```
from itertools import groupby

items = [1,2,3,4,5]
items2 = [2,3,4]
items3 = [1,2,5]
items4 = [2,3,4,5]


results = {value: len(list(freq)) for value, freq in groupby(sorted(items))}

print(results)
```

Here how do I get the occurrence of each element in all the arrays?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the name of the array to items1,items2,items3... (last number numerically incrementing), you can use the code below. You will have to update the range to match your number of arrays (plus 1).

```
from itertools import groupby
items1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
items2 = [2,3,4]
items3 = [1,2,5]
items4 = [2,3,4,5]
item_list=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    item_list.append('items'+str(i))
num_list=[]
for item in item_list:
    num_list += eval(item)
a= set(num_list)

results = {value: len(list(freq)) for value, freq in groupby(sorted(num_list))}

print(results)
```

**Output**

```
{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3}
```

Comment: Ah I found the logic. Thanks @moys

Comment: @Wadood_sultan If the answer helped, can you consider Up-voting/Accepting the answer?